# PHP:: Cleaner preg_match_all results

Tags: php, loops, foreach, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to fetch a value from external html page.

Now this do the magic for me :

```
preg_match_all('/id="localWeather">(.*?)<\/div>/',$returnedPage,$returnValues,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

But after this line I need to loop the results and clean it.

Why? because I only need this `(.*?)` and for some reason it return also add the extra `</div>` closing tag so I need to loop it and clean the array afterwards.

My question is how do I force to return only this : `(.*?)` ?

Comment: `$returnValues[0][1]` should not have `</div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `PREG_SET_ORDER`. Example:

```
<?php

$returnedPage = '<div id="localWeather">test</div><div id="localWeather">test2</div>';

preg_match_all('/id="localWeather">(.*?)<\/div>/',$returnedPage,$returnValues);

print_r($returnValues);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id="localWeather">test</div>
            [1] => id="localWeather">test2</div>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => test2
        )

)
```

So in this case, `$returnValues[1]` is an array of matches with just the content in between the divs (and not the closing div), while `$returnValues[0]` is an array of the entire portion of the string that matched your regex.

Also, using regular expressions isn't recommended to parse HTML. I'd look at PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) class instead, it's more robust.

Comment: This works fine with `PREG_SET_ORDER` as well, just different array structure.

Comment: Yep, but I interpreted the request as getting just an array of the results. If you only want that, with PREG_SET_ORDER you'd have to loop through the array.

Comment: I thought they meant they were getting something like `test</div>`, which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed one of two things: They aren't getting </div> they are getting </DIV> or something else which doesn't match the regex, or they were interpreting the matches wrong and looking at the wrong array.

Comment: Working perfectly ! Just thought that it's possible to do it directly with 
preg_match_all... probably not ?

Comment: Sadly not, stuck with the current way :(